# Creating global variables inside function - why does this work?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global, local

As far as I know variables declared inside a function are local variables (using `var` keyword or not).
If so then why does this output `5`? Shouldn't I get a `ReferenceError` when calling `func2` because `x` is only known to `func1`?

```
<script>
    function func1(){
       x = 5;
    }

    function func2(){
       document.write(x);
    }

    func1();
    func2();
</script>
```

Comment: _"variables declared inside a function"_, which you didnt do as you did not use `let` or `var`

Comment: Variables are local when declared with `val`. Otherwise they're global.

Comment: Read up on [JavaScript Scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Afaik, variables declared inside a function are local variables (using var keyword or not).

Variables *declared* inside a function are local, but you are not declaring any variables. What you have is what's known as an "implicit global" and it only works in "sloppy mode".

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed.

In strict mode, your code produces an error:

```js
"use strict";

function func1() {
  x = 5;
}

function func2() {
  document.write(x);
}

func1();
func2();
```

Comment: so there actually is a way to create globals inside functions. thanks!

Comment: @onTheFence Yes, it is possible, but it's a very bad idea. That's why it produces an error in strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you did not define it as

```
function func1(){
   var x = 5;
}
```

This means that JS will use the global variable `x` which does not exist, but will when you run func1.

The addition of the "var" defines the variable within the local scope of `func1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function func1(){
   x = 5;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
var x; // In global scope
function func1(){
   x = 5;
}
```

As the variable was not scoped to `func1` with a declaration.

If this was the case, then you would come across an error in the console since you are trying to access a variable that is not defined yet.

```
function func1(){
   var x = 5;
}
```

Comment: It throws such a reference error in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";

function func1() {
  window.x = 5;
}

function func2() {
  document.write(x);
}

func1();
func2();
```

Comment: using window.x=5 you can access it outside the function also.